# Wordpress theme functions.php not used for non-loggedin users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function to redirect users to the login page if they are not logged in for some pages, this is my code:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in())                                           //déjà identifié
        return;
    

    if (preg_match('#secured-page#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
    {
        header( 'location: /wp-login.php' );
        exit();
    }
});
```

As it didn't work and I tried every simplifications I tried to add a `print "hello"` at the beginning of the parent and child theme `functions.php` nothing is printed if the user is not logged in.

Aren't theme functions supposed to be called everywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I had a cache extension, then when I was logged in the cache was not used but in the other case the server was serving me the cached page which looked like if the function.php was not called.
The solution was to clear the cache.

Answer (score 2):

To your question "Aren't theme functions supposed to be called everywhere?" The answer is yes. I can confirm this code works as intended for me:

**functions.php** (child or parent)

```php
add_action('init', function () {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] !== 'wp-login.php' && preg_match('#secured-page#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        wp_safe_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/wp-login.php')));
        exit();
    }
});
```

The only thing I can say based on your code is there is either an issue with `preg_match('#secured-page#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` always being false, or some other code is interfering. Can you confirm your code makes it to `preg_match('#secured-page#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and that it is returning `1` for the correct scenarios?

Rather than using the PHP `header()` function use the WordPress `wp_safe_redirect()` function. It eventually calls the PHP `header()` but does a number of other checks and sanitizations that other code may need to have run first before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a php header call, you need to load it straight from in between the head tag from your `header.php` file. the following should work straight away.

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_admin() ):
$redirect = esc_url( home_url( '/wp-admin' ) );
wp_redirect( $redirect );
exit;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: header calls need to happen before anything is output to the response body. Once you start sending the `<head>` tag, the headers will be closed.

Comment: Your code should generally work because of the way the way WordPress does it's hooks. Basically meaning WP will normally wait for a hook in the wp_head() call before sending the headers. However this is not guaranteed. Also, if the redirect happens after the wp_head() within the head tag, it should throw an error as well. Its best to avoid this all together and make sure you send headers before html gets created. Ideally, you want to send the location header as soon as possible. I thought it was worth noting because it's against best practices and there will be situations were this will break.